# Use 220v appliances on Japan 200v: how to connect

Tags: voltage

I've posted this question in the electrical engineering and they have recommended to do over here, so here I am :)

I’m trying to understand how I can connect my European appliances to the 200v supplied here in Japan I’m sure is possible because, during the renovation, my electrician was able to connect a kitchen hood from Germany, but I don’t know how he did and I can’t connect with him anymore I’ve tried a simple 3 pins plug replacement (phase neutral ground) but didn’t worked out

Sorry for my lack of basic knowledge :)

Thanks to all in advance for share your knowledge with me

Cheers

Comment: The most efficient method to convert an appliance to Japan voltage is Craigslist/Europe/sell -> Craigslist/Japan/buy.  Also saves on shipping costs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Japan 200V is analogous to United States 240V.  It is not similar to European 230V in that in the US/JP arrangement, neither wire is neutral, and ground is in the center.

That means, if your Euro appliance is polarized to make contact with neutral less dangerous, *surprise! Neutral is now dangerous!*

Also, in the USA-style system, they don't use whole-house RCD, they use RCDs per individual branch circuit. Typically, RCDs are omitted on 240V circuits, since they are only used on large appliances with good grounding, like dryers or table saws. This is a *recipe for disaster* if you're using ungrounded 240V small appliances in a kitchen or bathroom! Make sure your 240V small appliance circuits are placed on RCD (called GFCI), and 240V GFCIs are expensive beasts.

Also in parts of Japan you have 60Hz power not 50Hz.

We can't give generic appliance advice.  You need to consult the labeling and instructions of each appliance to see whether the manufacturer has certified it for use on the different power frequency (heaters fine; motors not so much) and somewhat lower voltage.  Some appliances will be multi-voltage and will cheerfully take anything from 100V (JP) to 240V (UK).

If it's not certified, that's probably *for a reason* - they wouldn't count themselves out of the Japanese market unless they had to. Check with the local Japanese authorities as to the legality of using the appliance.  I would be reluctant to use such an appliance.

Comment: Dear Harper, thanks so much for your detailed answer! So it seems that the easiest way is replace the motor with a local one to avoid any issue. I thought it was easier but it isn't, is very clear now. Cheers